# Metering pump that is either computer compatible or microcontroller compatible?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, industrial-engineering

I'd like to write something in Python to automate and maintain a specific dosing formula for a couple of our processes. We need a dosing pump that either has a USB port that can interact with a computer or a microcontroller. Do any manufacturers make pumps like this? Thanks!

Comment: check the chemical and biological lab supply houses for a programmable peristaltic pump.

Comment: Also commercial laundry metering and dishwashing pumps. One [example](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/dema-t-812-ll-titan-ii-liquid-detergent-and-rinse-aid-chemical-dispenser-pump/307T812LL.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=CjwKCAiAy4bTBRAvEiwAFtatHCcw8fDUVRbrGMsVWOGi54ZXKOOULa0UOfgYu3UuICLlhlox47-KhxoCBOkQAvD_BwE)

Comment: If you don't dinf anything, some dosing pumps are profibus compatible.

Comment: Can you include more details in your question? What's the required flow rate? Any pressure requirements? Accuracy/Tolerance on the dosing?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure most dosing/metering pump manufacturers provide some degree of what you are asking for.  I know that we have used Prominent before and they make metering pumps that can be controlled with a 4-20 mA signal, as do several other manufacturers (I think I have seen some from Grundfos also).
Prominent also sells controllers that you can integrate with pumps to control via various means.
I imagine most dosing pump manufacturers will also sell you a package setup that will have everything you need (Prominent has them here: https://www.prominent.com/en/Products/Products/Metering-Systems/Metering-Systems-for-Liquids/p-dulcodos-modular.html), though you will likely need to spend a little time talking to the manufacturer or vendor you want to go with so that you get an appropriate system.  With pumps, there's not really a one-size-fits-all product, so you will need to have a little data before you start ordering anything.

[I am not affiliated with ProMinent, I just happened to have used them recently on a project, and it made it easy to quickly find their product data for my answer]

Answer (score 0):

A few pumps might take a 4-20 mA signal, and you might be able to find a microcontroller which would generate 4-20mA.

I would suggest to look at dosing pumps that are used for boiler feed chemicals.

Comment: Why not drive the pump with a relay and forget about the current rating of the MC?

Comment: Thats a great idea. That will give you on off control only, but some of those small pumps have hand knobs you can turn to adjust dose size.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no mention of volume per dose, so for smaller applications, how about using a peristaltic pump which you can control in finite increments:

￼[image: peristaltic pump]